# How should I add C++ header files in this CMakeLists.txt file?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmakelists-options

[image]

**`CMakeLists.txt`**

```
add_library(systems
AtomTypes.cc
AtomTypingVariants.cc
BuildPolymerChain.cc
CartesianAtoms.cc
CartesianChains.cc
SimpleAtomTyping.cc
)

add_subdirectory(surpass)

target_link_libraries(systems
PRIVATE
surpass
)
```

I added source files, and now I need to add header files in the above file.

Is the above file correct?

How should I add header files in the above `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Should I use `target_sources()` with `PUBLIC` qualifier or `add_libraries()`?

Comment: Just add them to the list with .cc files.

Comment: "now I need to add header files in the above file" - **Why** (for what **purpose**) do you want to add header files to your `CMakeLists.txt`? Do you want header files to be shown in IDE? In that case, add them among sources in `add_library` call. Or do you want to add headers for being able to include them in your sources? Then specify appropriate include directory or set variable [CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR.html) for automatically include current directory. Your question is **unclear**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the build logic it doesn't make a difference whether you're adding the header files to the source list or not. I recommend adding them nonetheless, since this results in IDEs like Visual Studio listing those files as sources for the target. You could list those header files in the same place you translation units (.cc files).

```
add_library(...
    AtomTypes.cc
    AtomTypes.hh
    ...
)
```

---

> Should I use `target_sources()` with `PUBLIC` qualifier or `add_libraries()`?

Whether you're using `target_sources` or `add_libraries` to add sources or headers is your choice. In general you should be using `target_sources(... PRIVATE ...)` though, since any sources listed with `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` visibility will become part of linking targets as well.

Personally I tend to list sources and headers that are always part of a target in the command creating the target and use `target_sources` as a way to add sources that are conditionally included. You could also create list variables for this purpose though.

```
add_library(foo STATIC
    a.cpp
    a.hpp
    b.cpp
    b.hpp
    c.hpp
)

if (WIN32)
    target_sources(foo PRIVATE c.win.cpp)
else()
    target_sources(foo PRIVATE c.other.cpp)
endif()
```

or

```
set(SOURCES
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
)

set(HEADERS
    a.hpp
    b.hpp
    c.hpp
)

if (WIN32)
    list(APPEND SOURCES c.win.cpp)
else()
    list(APPEND SOURCES c.other.cpp)
endif()

add_library(foo STATIC ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
```